# Using NUnit from Visual Studio to MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, monodevelop

I get this error when I try to run unit tests on a solution originally from Visual Studio: RemotingException: Unix transport error.

I originally let MonoDevelop grab it's own NuGet packages including NUnit 2.6.4, NUnit.Runners 2.6.4, and NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0. I then tried using the 2.6.3 references included with MonoDevelop and getting rid of NuGet packages including NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0. I also tried using NUnit 3.0.1. All of these resulted in the same errors. How can I get NUnit to work with this solution?

The project can be found at: https://github.com/ParagonTruss/GeometryClassLibrary

[image: RemotingException]

[image: References]

Comment: The Visual Studio Adapter is not going to work within XS/MD : https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/57

Comment: I got rid of the Visual Studio Adapter and it still did not work.

Comment: NUnit 3.0 is not supported in XS. NUnit 2.6.4 and older versions should work fine. I would look in the IDE log to see if there is more information about the error (Help - Open Log Directory).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when I reinstalled the NUnit Visual Studio Test Adapter in Visual Studio it would change `<Private>True</Private>` in the .csproj file to `<Private>False</Private>` and then worked fine in MonoDevelop.